# The most tiny programming language

Tags: programming-languages

I would like to know what is the most tiny programming language in aspects of commands i.e, which includes the least number of commands.

Is it brainf***k?

Comment: How is this too broad? I think that Rishit's answer answers the question well.

Comment: as far as i know binary is the smallest one. just 2 commands `0` and `1`

Answer (score 5):

Subtract and Branch if Negative (SBN) is a single instruction computer. And it is Turing complete, which means any computer program can be solved using just above instruction.

Such computer is called [One Instruction Set Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer). There are several possible single instruction that can be used, some of which are:

1. Subtract and branch if less than or equal to zero
2. Subtract and branch if negative
3. Reverse subtract and skip if borrow
4. Subtract and branch if non zero

Comment: I am looking for an existing prohramming language, not a command...

Comment: Programming language is a set of instruction used to control behavior of machine. And above command is a complete programming language in itself. As I said, you can write any computer program using above single instruction (or programming language).